# Argo worflows - fair share resources

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows

Is is possible to schedule two (or more) Argo workflows on a Kubernetes cluster concurrently and share the cluster resources between the two 50/50? I'm looking for a resource awareness capability, if it exists in Argo or another workflow engine.

Cheers.

Comment: You can specify resource requirements on steps in a Workflow just like you would a Deployment. Would that work, or do you need something that more aggressively enforces the split?

Comment: I just need a way to guarantee a given workflow will have x amount of cluster capacity reserved for its utilisation. Would requests and limits work here?

Comment: I’m pretty sure Argo does not have a native mechanism to guarantee that. I’m not even sure what “50% of cluster capacity” would mean, technically. (Is it average CPU/memory usage over time? If so, what period of time? What if one workflow has high CPU usage but low memory usage? How would it be balanced against one with low CPU but high memory?) But I think requests and limits would definitely get you some semblance of that.

Comment: I guess I am looking for guarantees of concurrency. If one workflow is CPU heavy then its limited to only take x% of the capacity which is determined by the number of concurrent workflows we are scheduling.

Comment: https://volcano.sh is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to guarantee a dynamic even split between the two processes. Nor am I aware of such a thing existing on any workflow engine as it sounds very hard to execute well.

What you can and should do as a best practice is specify the workflow compute [requirements](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/fields/#resourcerequirements). You can specify memory and CPU request and limits. There is no reason to give a pod an "endless" amount of resources if it has a certain task to perform.

If you have a pod that could potentially require all available resources I recommend splitting it into several smaller workloads. then you could control other parameters that affect resource usage like concurrency
through argo.